# setFrequency in FMOD doesn't work satisfactorily

Tags: audio, fmod

I'm trying to use FMOD to develop an application that is expected to be able to play audio more slowly than normal so that the user could hear the audio more clearly. In my code, I called **Channel::setFrequency** like this:

```
float normal_frequency;
channel->getFrequency(&normal_frequency);
channel->setFrequency(normal_frequency * speedSelected);
```

If the value of **speedSelected** is lower than 1, for example 0.8, the audio will indeed be played more slowly than normal, but the voice sounds really odd. Playing slowly doesn't enable me to hear audio more clearly at all.

By contrast, Microsoft's **Windows Media Player** works perfectly when it plays audio more slowly than normal.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If by *"sounds really odd"* you mean the pitch has been altered then this is the expected outcome. If you want to correct the pitch while adjusting the speed you will need to use the pitch shifter DSP.